# GET http://registry.npmjs.org/download/@a2nt/ss-bootstrap-ui-webpack-boilerplate-react/4.3.0/4db7Not Found - 404

Tags: npm, pnpm

Run the `pnpm install`. I got following error
[image]

how can I solve this error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when the lockfile was created, a different registry was used. This registry that was used during the creation of the lockfile uses a different URL format for storing the package tarballs.

In the public npmjs registry, the URL of that package would be:

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/@a2nt/ss-bootstrap-ui-webpack-boilerplate-react/-/ss-bootstrap-ui-webpack-boilerplate-react-4.3.0.tgz
```

To fix this issue either change your registry to the one that was used during the lockfile creation.

Or remove the lockfile (`pnpm-lock.yaml`), the `node_modules` directory and run `pnpm install`. This will create a new lockfile with correct tarball URLs.